# Importing a c++module on python

Tags: python, c++, ros, catkin

I'm trying to import a C++ module on a `python script`.
I'm using pycharm community edition 2017.3.3 as IDE and `catkin` as build system.
The IDE is able to recognize my importing statement.

```
import hector_path_follower
```

My problem is having access to c++ namespace that wraps the class and cannot being found (`unresolved reference`)
For instance, I cannot access pose_follower namespace that wraps my class.

```
pf = pose_follower.HectorPathFollower()

namespace pose_follower {
class HectorPathFollower
 { 
...
 }
}
```

I had looked around and saw about boost library, ctypes etc.

Comment: I've got this answer https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/279347/importar-m%C3%B3dulos-c-em-python/279434#279434] but it is in portuguese. Basically, it comments about some libraries. modules and compare then. In my opinion, I would try `swig` and as a second choice `boost`